# MySqlDataReader.Read() throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: mysql, .net, connector

I'm working with mysql .net connector 6.4.4 at win7 x64 platform. While reading data from MySqlDataReader Object, it throws exception after 18th row. But in another application I could take 40 rows without errors.

The error is just here:

MySqlDataReader.Read()

Any helps would be very appreciated.

```
Exception details:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=count
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket.Read(Byte[] byteBuffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPacket.ReadString(Int64 length)
       at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlString.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.ReadValue(MySqlPacket packet, Int64 length, Boolean nullVal)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue value)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()
       at VeriTasima.Form1..ctor() in E:\Projeler\VeriTasima\VeriTasima\Form1.cs:line 42
       at VeriTasima.Program.Main() in E:\Projeler\VeriTasima\VeriTasima\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Updated:

```
// test
            string commandString = "SELECT * FROM haber LIMIT 50";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                count++;
            }
            sdr.Close();
            sdr.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

Updated:

I fixed this problem by setting target platfrom from x86 to Any CPU. Now works properly.

Comment: can you show the SqlCommand you are using? As the error message says you have a parameter with the name count which can't be negative.

Comment: I don't get it either, though why you are looping through client side instead of doing Select Count(*) From Haber Limit 50 raised an eyebrow.

Comment: This is just a simplified code, only for testing.

Comment: and does the stack trace you posted go with this simple example, or it is the actual one?

Comment: Yes, this code is also failes. The count parameter above is        at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) own to this method.

Comment: What is in that table?  If you just select a single column does it throw an exception?

Comment: The only thing I can see is ,maybe there's  mismatch of one of the data types. It would be interesting to see what would happen if you changed the query to Select 'PrimaryKeyID' From Haber limit 50 instead of *

Comment: Almost certainly an internal MySQL error/bug